# How do I get the DSN driver information?

Tags: c++, odbc

I can use the function SQLDataSources to get the DSN name and the description and I can use the function SQLBrowseConnect to get the driver information.

I need to get the driver information which relates to each DSN but there does not seem to be a link between the above functions, anyone know how to bridge the gap?

Edit:

I can successfully use the SQLBrowseConnection function but most ODBC DSNs give the error that the function is not implemented.  Anyone got any other ideas?

The information I want is the data column in Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources in Windows.  I cannot use the registry key directly though as I need to support other operating systems.

Comment: AFAIR driver description returned by SQLDataSources is ODBC driver name so you can pass it to SQLBrowseConnect function with InConnectionString argument ("DRIVER = <driver_description>")

Comment: @oleque, I keep getting an error returned when I try this though :-(

Comment: AFAIR the information from "the data column in Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources in Windows" can be read with SQLDataSources function in Windows. It is returned via Description, BufferLength2 and NameLength2Ptr arguments.